# Laravel Custom Validation Class get parameter value properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a class which checks two dates and sees if the value is greater than or equal to the second parameter. My question is - how do you properly get the value from the second field I've used Input::get($value_to_compare) which I don't think is actually the correct way to go about it.

```
class CoreValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

protected function validateDateLessThanOrEqualTo($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{

    /*
     * If a input with the name equal to the value we compare with, we
     * use it, otherwise we proceed as usual
     */

    if( isset( $this->attributes[ $parameters[0] ] ) )
    {

      $value_to_compare = $this->attributes[ $parameters[0] ];

    }//if we have an input with this name
    else
    {

        $value_to_compare = $parameters[0];

    }//we compare with the provided value



    return ( date_parse( $value ) <= date_parse( Input::get($value_to_compare) ) );

}   

protected function replaceDateLessThanOrEqualTo($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{


    return str_replace(':other', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $parameters[0])), $message);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the member variable `$data` on the validator object to get the other attributes's value:

```
return ( date_parse( $value ) <= date_parse( $this->data[$value_to_compare] ) );
```